# What will "He always wears a suit to work. " be in predicate language?

Tags: predicate-logic

Please check my answer:

$\forall x[H_x \supset W_x ]$ which translates as "For all x, *if* x is **h**e  (goes to work) *then* he **w**ears suit to work" (Bold ones are the symbols I pickedup)

Venn would a diagram for an *A* proposition shown as:

[image: A proposition image]

Comment: I do not agree that "he" is $\forall x$; the quantifier means "every" and to say "Everyone that goes to work..." is not the same as "He  goes ..."

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty weird symbolization key:

$Hx$: $x$ is 'He'

$Wx$: $x$ always wears a suit to work

Indeed, as such, your logic sentence, when translated back into English, would be: 'All that are 'he' always wear a suit to work'

I would say: if the 'he' is some specific person, then use an individual constant for this person, say $h$

Then, you can use the following more 'natural' predicates:

$Wx$: $x$ goes to work

$Sx$: $x$ wears a suit

And with that, we can symbolize the sentence as:

$Wh \to Sh$

Now, this seems to be missing the 'always' part though ... but note that that is about points in time, not people

So, to add that in, you can do:

$Wxt$: $x$ goes to work at time $t$

$Sxt$: $x$ wears a suit at time $t$

And then the translation is:

$\forall t (Wht \to Sht)$

(I'll forgo making a remark on what that last translation looks like ...)